# How does Geany auto-completion wơrk?

Tags: autocomplete, ide, geany

About the auto-complete features of Geany:

- does it have auto-complete?
- for which languages does it have auto-complete (plugins?)?
- how do I use auto-complete?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Geany does have autocomplete.

The main way autocomplete is used is by typing a long word, and by narrowing that list of autocomplete possibilities down.  Let's say you type gtk_combo_box_.  It will have a small list of different commands that match this description.  Typing eTAB will narrow the search down to gtk_combo_box_entry_.  Typing sENTER will then bring it to the proper to gtk_combo_entry_set_text_column.  See [the Geany manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#id52).

Answer (score 23):

You can simply use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: To autocomplete project methods, you have to have the file open with declaration of the method.

Answer (score 16):

The correct answer is:

Menu *Edit* → *Preferences* → *Editor* → *Completions* → check the *"Autocomplete all words in document"* checkbox.
Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: Also you want to decrease the number of needed character for autocomplete. At least I prefer 2 instead of 4.

Comment: Re *"Press Ctrl + Space"*: Not inside the preferences dialog, presumably?

Answer (score 8):

Geany uses its own internal engine and is currently limited to:

- [C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29)
- [Pascal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29)
- [PHP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP)
- [HTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML)
- [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX)
- [Python](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29)

Its file format uses three types of encoding:

- Tagmanager format
- Pipe-separated format
- [Ctags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags) format

With Ctags, you can use the external and powerful `ctags` utility that supports a lot of languages.

Refer to the official documentation, *[Symbols and tags files](https://www.geany.org/manual/current/#symbols-and-tags-files)*.

Answer (score 4):

Geany surely has autocomplete and can offer a list of possible completions for symbols defined in the tags and for all words in a document.

The autocompletion list for symbols is presented when the first few characters of the symbol are typed  or when the *complete word* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>) keybinding is pressed.

When the defined keybinding is typed and the *Autocomplete all words in document* preference is selected, then the autocompletion list will show all matching words **previously mentioned** in the document, if there aren't any matching symbols.

[image]

[image]

Autocompletion also can be based on specific words, like keywords, etc. For this, you can check *[AutoCompletion for my DSL keywords in Geany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28920407/autocompletion-for-my-dsl-keywords-in-geany)*.

Comment: Note to self: it will only activate the menu after x characters are typed, and x may be bigger than you think/hope.

Answer (score 4):

As the [manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#symbols-and-tags-files) states:

> Upon opening, files of supported filetypes are parsed to extract the
>   symbol information (aka "workspace symbols"). You can also have Geany
>   automatically load external files containing the symbol information
>   (aka "global tags files") upon startup, or manually using Tools -->
>   Load Tags File.
>
> Global tags files are used to provide symbols for autocompletion and
>   calltips without having to open the source files containing these
>   symbols. This is intended for library APIs, as the tags file only has
>   to be updated when you upgrade the library.
>
> Some global tags files are distributed with Geany and will be loaded
>   automatically when the corresponding filetype is first used. Currently
>   this includes global tags files for these languages: C, Pascal, PHP,
>   HTML, LaTeX, Python

For other languages, like Java, you have to download a tag file from [here](http://wiki.geany.org/tags/start) (if available), and load it upon startup or manually.

Comment: Thanks for the Java info. Somehow I expected this to be more obvious to newbies. Beneath all this non-out-of-the-box setup there may be a really good tool.

Comment: Thanks, the site you provided is great. To load tags automatically at startup one have to place the tag file in geany directory. In my Ubuntu it is `/home/YOUR_NAME/.config/geany/tags`