# AutoCompletion for my DSL keywords in Geany

Tags: autocomplete, ide, dsl, geany

Geany (IDE) supports autocompletion or IntelliSense as you program, but this is done based on the words you've used in the code so far.

Is there a way I could have autocompletion for my language keywords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by writing your own tag file. It should be name like `<somename>.<filetype>.tags` and can be stored, e.g., inside .geany-folder or inside global folders. You can import it via the *Tools* menu.

The tag file contains of a list of your methods, functions, etc. of your language, as well as optimally some options for these commands used a tooltip. You can find some details inside [the manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/index.html#global-tags-file-format).

Of course, you could also check the [Geany wiki](http://wiki.geany.org/tags/start) whether there might be already some tag file available for your language.